# Cant load up image because of PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-imaging-library

I am trying to import something from PIL:

```
from PIL import ImageTK, Image
```

But this error is flagged up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I have tried `pip install PIL` and `easy_install PIL` and the error is still flagged up
pls can u help me? Im coding in Sublime text btw

Comment: The problem seems to be that the install failed. What message did you get in response to `pip install PIL`?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pillow, may be this can solve your issue:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed `PIL` in python2, but you are now in python3
You can install `PIL` for python3 by using `pip3`

```
pip3 install PIL
```

If this does not work, consider opening a virtual environment and install `PIL` there, it might work out.

Answer (score 0):

Error means no downloaded library so try to install the library.
In the terminal enter:

```
pip install Pillow
```

or:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```